# Restoring images, footer and page number no the Notes Page for all slides of a deck

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've got a number of large slide decks that have been edited by multiple people with slides from multiple sources.

The Notes Page has a layout with a header image, a copyright in the footer and a page number in the footer. I've re-applied the notes page to all slides, but some slides are still missing the image, the copyright or the page number. I'm yet to find a way (other than creating a new slide with the same layout and copy-pasting the contents) to make the missing elements to re-appear.

The Notes Page:

[image: Notes page as it should be]

Working on some pages:

[image: Working notes page on some slides]

But not working on others:

[image]

I've tried using the Reapply Notes Master feature to no avail:

[image]

I've tried removing and re-adding the footer, page number and header templates to no avail.

I suspect these templates were manually removed from the slides somehow.

Anyone have a way (possibly using VBA) to restore these?

I'm willing to unzip the pptx and transform the XML if I have to :).

Comment: Looks like someone deleted those placeholders from the slides in question, in Notes view. Rather than copying content to a new slide, is it possibly quicker to copy those placeholders (all at once) from a "good" slide and paste to the broken ones?

Comment: @AdamV probably, but can't add the image back in that way. I ended up scripting a solution through manipulating the XML innards of the powerpoint file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got angry enough. So I whipped up some powershell to put the body from the broken slidenotes into a "known-good" slidenote.

To do so I did the following:

1. I made the slidenotes master appear exactly as I wanted it to.
2. I created a new 1st slide to ensure I had at least 1 slide with the correct master.
3. I extracted the pptx to a folder (unzip it with 7zip or similar tool)
4. I wrote some powershell to take the content from each existing slidenote body and put it into the known-good master layout.
5. I added functionality to take the slide number from the notes page file name.
6. I overwrote the original notesSlideXXX.xml in the script
7. I copied `notesSlide1.xml` to `master.xml` to tell my script what to use as master.
8. I ran the script from the `xxx.pptm\ppt\notesSlides\` folder
9. I zipped the pptx back up.

```
$notes = Get-ChildItem -path "." -Filter notes*.xml -File

foreach ($notesFile in $notes)
{
    $notesFile.Name
    $notesFile.Name -match "\d+"
    $slideNumber = $Matches[0]

    [xml] $slideNotes = Get-Content $notesFile
    [xml] $master = Get-Content .\master.xml

    $ns = @{ 
        a = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" 
        r = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
        p = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" 
    }

    $bodycontent = $slideNotes | Select-XML "(//p:sp[.//p:ph[@type='body']])[1]" -Namespace $ns
    
    $masterbodycontent = $master | Select-XML "(//p:sp[.//p:ph[@type='body']])[1]" -Namespace $ns
    $masterbodycontent.Node.InnerXml = $bodycontent.Node.InnerXml

    $masterslidenumcontent = $master | Select-XML "(//p:sp//a:fld[@type='slidenum']/a:t)[1]" -Namespace $ns
    $masterslidenumcontent.Node.InnerText = $slideNumber

    $master.Save($notesFile)
}
```

This completely and fully reset all the slides' notes layouts.

Me = happy.